# How to stop a running app from command line

Tags: ios, xcode

My iphone is attached to my computer and an app is running from xcode

I want to stop an app that is currently running on the iphone through xcode, using a command line command.

There is a cmd + . to do that in the xcode interface, but i want to write an  automated script, and for that i need to make sure that xcode is not running anything before it starts executing.

What do i need to send to the command line or xcode app? to make it stop running whatever its running at the moment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do `killall debugserver` to terminate the currently running session.

I apologize if this doesn't work for iOS as I am a Mac developer, but I see no reason it shouldn't work the same.

[Here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Debugserver) is, hopefully, some useful information on `debugserver`